# add hyperlink to getElementsByTagName

Tags: html, getelementsbytagname

I'm retrieving the XML Node Value into my HTML page. There is a path in one of my nodes and I would like to place a link around it.  The TagName is ("link")  I need to add the value of the TagName "link" to be hyperlinked.  I tried using

How is this done?

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        else {// code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "reports.xml", false);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

                        //document.write("<tr><th width='18%' align='left'>Report</th>");
                        //document.write("<th width='18%' align='left'>Audit Subject</th>");
                        //document.write("<th width='18%' align='left'>Report</th></tr>");

                        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            document.write("<tr><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</td><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("<br>");
                            document.write("<a href='' target='_blank'>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</a></td><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubdate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</td></tr>");

                        }
```

XML File:

```
`<audits>
  <reports>
    <title>Audit Reports</title>
    <rsslink>http://www.somesite.com/</rsslink>
    <item>
      <title>test1</title>
      <description>test for hyperlink path</description>
      <link>../pdf/audits/DeonGeeCert.pdf</link>
      <pubdate>Friday, September 21, 2012</pubdate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>test2</title>
      <description>test2</description>
      <link>../pdf/audits/2012-09-10audit-12-14.pdf</link>
      <pubdate>Monday, September 10, 2012</pubdate>
    </item>`
```

Comment: is the code even related to your question.. anyways can you please show us an example of the responseXML and the corresponding output that you expect.. also setup a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net too

Comment: and if you want it to be a link tag shouldnt you precede it with <a>

Comment: I'm sorry - i resubmitted the question. Also what is jsFiddle and how do I use it?  I just set up an account don't know what its for.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about what you want, your question is too vague but I am guessing this is probably what you want to do

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            document.write("<tr><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</td><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("<br>");
                            var linkValue=x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            document.write("<a href='"+linkValue+"' target='_blank'>");
                            document.write(linkValue);  //or some meaningful text, just keeping the last string in the link
                            document.write("</a></td><td>");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubdate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</td></tr>");

                    }
```

Comment: That is it,  you are brilliant.  Thank you so much.  I am new with this and was trying to ask the question the best way I could.  It worked perfectly.